# VB.net Terminal Server application

Tags: vb.net, terminal-services

im working on an terminal service application for personal use that allows me to list and manage all my RDP sessions via tabs (I know these exists, but using it as a small learning project also). I was wondering if anyone could help with a few items. I am trying to dynamically create and add tabs and the RDP control onto each tab. This seems to be working OK for creating the first tab page and control but fails on the subsequent ones with the error below Code below:

```
    Dim theNewTabPage As New DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage()
    theNewTabPage.Text = txtserver.Text
    theNewTabPage.Name = Minute(DateTime.Now) & Second(DateTime.Now)

    Dim RDPCONTROL As New AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting
    RDPCONTROL.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    'Just a test to ensure unique name
    RDPCONTROL.Name = Minute(DateTime.Now) & Second(DateTime.Now) 
    XtraTabControl1.TabPages.Add(theNewTabPage)
    theNewTabPage.Controls.Add(RDPCONTROL)
    Try
        RDPCONTROL.Server = txtserver.Text
        RDPCONTROL.Domain = txtdomain.text
        RDPCONTROL.UserName = txtusername.Text
        Dim secured As MSTSCLib.IMsTscNonScriptable = DirectCast(RDPCONTROL.GetOcx(), MSTSCLib.IMsTscNonScriptable)
        secured.ClearTextPassword = txtpassword.Text
        RDPCONTROL.Connect()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try`
```

Error when creating the second connection:

```
Using ex.message: exception of type 'system.windows.forms.axhost+invalidactivexstateexception  was thrown
Using ex.tostring: property set of 'Server' cannot be invoked at this time
```

The next item is how can i detect if the RDP session was disconnected on the tab and then pop-up a message and close the required tab

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around i was able to solve this by calling:

```
XtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage = newTabPage
```

Just after i added the new tab page.
Hope this helps someone in the future